# NGramTokenizer not working as expected

Tags: r, ggplot2, n-gram

I have a simple R code where I'm reading text from a file and plotting recurring phrases on a bar chart. For some reason, the bar chart only shows single words rather than multi worded phrases. Where am I going wrong?

```
install.packages("xlsx")
install.packages("tm")
install.packages("wordcloud")
install.packages("ggplot2")

library(xlsx)
library(tm)
library(wordcloud)
library(ggplot2)

setwd("C://Users//608447283//desktop//R_word_charts")


test <- Corpus(DirSource"C://Users//608447283//desktop//R_word_charts//source"))

test <- tm_map(test, stripWhitespace)
test <- tm_map(test, tolower)
test <- tm_map(test, removeWords,stopwords("english"))
test <- tm_map(test, removePunctuation)
test <- tm_map(test, PlainTextDocument)

tok <- function(x) NGramTokenizer(x, Weka_control(min=3, max=10))
tdm <- TermDocumentMatrix(test,control = list(tokenize = tok))
termFreq <- rowSums(as.matrix(tdm))

termFreq <- subset(termFreq, termFreq>=50)

write.csv(termFreq,file="TestCSV1")
TestCSV <- read.csv("C:/Users/608447283/Desktop/R_word_charts/TestCSV1")

ggplot(data=TestCSV, aes(x=X, y=x)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity") + theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1))
```

My output:

[image]

Sample data:
[Sample data extract](https://www.dropbox.com/s/4v29v5x868yqktw/sample%20data.txt?dl=0)

Comment: what does your original data file look like ?

Comment: it's just a .txt file with lots of text

Comment: a data sample from that file would be helpful to reproduce the issue

Comment: @eliasah added a dropbox link to some sample data i'm using.

Comment: Hi @eliasah, have you managed to take a look at it? In absolute desperation here :/

Comment: I'm having troubles with the tm package. I'm working with R 3.2 on Linux and the package isn't available. On the other hand, I'd personally try to change weka controls

Comment: I did. None of it seems to work. When I `view(termFreq)` it shows me only single words. So some issue with `tok` and `tdm`

Comment: I asked the package contact person Ingo from whom i got the following answer "Instead of downgrading to tm 0.6-2 you can simply use "VCorpus" instead of "Corpus" when constructing a corpus from a source.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There seems to be an issue with the lastest version of the `tm` package (version 0.7).

Going back to version 0.6-2 should solve the 1-gram issue.

---

Another issue might be because of your data subset.

The filter (`termFreq <- subset(termFreq, termFreq>=50)`) was too permissive and it filtered out lots of valuable N-Grams. I'd rather use the top-N approach of visualizing the data. i.e :

```
library(tm)
library(ggplot2)
library(RWeka)
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)

setwd(dir = "/home/eliasah/Downloads/")
test <- Corpus(DirSource("/home/eliasah/Downloads/sample/"))

test <- tm_map(test, stripWhitespace)
test <- tm_map(test, tolower)
test <- tm_map(test, removeWords,stopwords("english"))
test <- tm_map(test, removePunctuation)
test <- tm_map(test, PlainTextDocument)

tok <- function(x) NGramTokenizer(x, Weka_control(min=3, max=10))
tdm <- TermDocumentMatrix(test,control = list(tokenize = tok))
termFreq <- rowSums(as.matrix(tdm))
termFreqVector <- as.list(termFreq)

test2 <- data.frame(unlist(termFreqVector), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
setDT(test2, keep.rownames = TRUE)[]
setnames(test2, 1, "term")
setnames(test2, 2, "freq")
test3 <- head(arrange(test2,desc(freq)), n = 30)

ggplot(data=test3, aes(x=reorder(term, freq), y=freq)) + geom_bar(stat="identity") + 
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1)) + coord_flip()
```

[image]

I hope this helps you solving your issue.

NB: I have used the data sample that you have linked in the question.

Comment: says "could not find function `arrange`". What could be the reason?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to add `library(dplyr)`. I have updated my answer !

Comment: @Anish Did you check it ?

Comment: I literally copy-pasted your code and it still gives me the same single words graph. :( http://imgur.com/5xpQ1rg

Comment: you are sure about it ? did you clear your R session ?

Comment: I cleared all the objects from the "Environment" tab and restarted R too. Still the same result. How is this even possible?

Comment: What versions of the packages used do you have ?

Comment: tm - 0.7, data.table - 1.10.4, dplyr - 0.5.0, ggplot2 - 2.2.1, RWeka - 0.4-31

Comment: I was working on my windows laptop so far. I just did a fresh install on my mac and tried to run your code. Still the same issue :(

Comment: I have this feeling that it's an issue with the tm package. I can't install that version on ubuntu since R 3.3.1 isn't supported yet.

Comment: What's the version you are using? I'll try to install an older version and see.

Comment: I don't have access to that computer now but I believe it's the 0.6.2

Comment: THAT WORKED!!!!!! It indeed was the tm package version issue. I installed 0.6-2 and it worked like a charm. But why is the latest version not giving the desired results? Anyways, I think you deserve complete credit for this. Can you edit your answer to include the tm version issue and i'll accept it as the answer. Thanks a lot for your help :)

Answer (score 3):

The bag is still there! But after asking the guys from the 'tm' package I used "VCorpus" instead of "Corpus" and now it is working.

Comment: oh now i saw that @Catherine Pfeifer also suggested this in a comment! I will leave this comment so it will be easier to see.