# Bigram Tokenization and Unigram Tokenizer

Tags: r

I'm having an issue of the Bigram tokenization displaying the same results as the ngram tokenization. It keeps showing only word vs two words on the graph. I'm a newbie at R and so I was trying to follow along with this tutorial:

https://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/40817_63c8586e26ea49d0a06bcba4e794e43d.html

I've used most of the code from the post, but have also tried to use some from a different source that I've been playing with. I did read that changing the corpus to a VCorpus cleared this issue up for several people. I did try changing this code: `corpus <- Corpus(review_source) to corpus <- VCorpus(review_source)` with the same results. Any guidance would be appreciated. Here is the code I'm currently working with

```
##Load in the data setwd("G:\\Customer Analytics\\AdHoc")
reviews <- read.csv("Reseller Ratings_clean.csv", stringsAsFactors = FALSE, 
header=TRUE)

review_text <- paste(reviews$reviews)

#setting up source and corpus
review_source <- VectorSource(review_text)
corpus <- Corpus(review_source)

########################
# Data Cleaning - Applying Transformations
########################
toSpace <- content_transformer(function(x, pattern) gsub(pattern, " ", x))
corpus <- tm_map(corpus, toSpace, "/|@|//|$|:|:)|*|&|!|?|_|-|#|")  ## 
replace special characters by space
corpus <- tm_map(corpus, content_transformer(tolower)) # Conversion to Lower 
Case
corpus <- tm_map(corpus, removePunctuation) # Punctuation can provide 
gramatical context which supports 
corpus <- tm_map(corpus, removeWords, stopwords("english")) # common stop 
Words like for, very, and, of, are, etc,
corpus <- tm_map(corpus, removeWords, c("the", "will", "The", "also", 
"that", "and", "for", "in", "is", "it", "not", "to"))
corpus <- tm_map(corpus, removeNumbers) # removal of numbers
corpus <- tm_map(corpus, stripWhitespace) # removal of whitespace
corpus <- tm_map(corpus, stemDocument) # Stemming uses an algorithm that 
removes common word endings for English

#Making a document-term matrix
dtm <- DocumentTermMatrix(corpus)

################################
# The transpose of the document term matrix 
################################
tdm <- TermDocumentMatrix(corpus)

# Frequency
freq <- sort(colSums(as.matrix(dtm)), decreasing=TRUE)
wf <- data.frame(word=names(freq), freq=freq)

# Plot Histogram
subset(wf, freq>500) %>%
ggplot(aes(word, freq)) +
geom_bar(stat="identity", fill="darkred", colour="darkgreen") +
theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=45, hjust=1))

# Create Wordcloud
library(wordcloud)
set.seed(100)
wordcloud(names(freq), freq, min.freq=100, colors=brewer.pal(6, "Dark2"))

###############################
# N-gram tokenization of the Corpus 
###############################
OnegramTokenizer <- function(x) NGramTokenizer(x, 
                                             Weka_control(min = 1, max =1))
dtm <- DocumentTermMatrix(docs, control = list(tokenize = OnegramTokenizer))
freq <- sort(colSums(as.matrix(dtm)), decreasing=TRUE)
wof <- data.frame(word=names(freq), freq=freq)

pl <- ggplot(subset(wof, freq > 500), aes(word, freq))
pl <- pl + geom_bar(stat="identity", fill="darkred", colour="blue")
pl + theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=45, hjust=1)) + ggtitle("Uni-Gram 
Frequency")

############################
# Bi-Gram Tokenization of the Corpus
############################

BigramTokenizer <- function(x) NGramTokenizer(x, 
                                            Weka_control(min = 2, max = 2))
dtm <- DocumentTermMatrix(docs, control = list(tokenize = BigramTokenizer))
freq <- sort(colSums(as.matrix(dtm)), decreasing=TRUE)
wof <- data.frame(word=names(freq), freq=freq)

pl <- ggplot(subset(wof, freq >500) ,aes(word, freq))
pl <- pl + geom_bar(stat="identity", fill="darkgreen", colour="blue")
pl + theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=45, hjust=1)) + ggtitle("Bi-Gram 
Frequency")
```

Comment: The close votes are for not providing a (minimal) reproducible example. You can not expect us to download all this data from coursera, and you have not supplied us with any data. If you want help, use one of the built-in data sets of tm, like the crude dataset. As for debugging, you are overwriting objects for unigram and bigram. Are you sure you ran the code correctly and in order for the bigrams / graphs?

Comment: I was able to get this to work. I had to change the corpus to a VCorpus and update my Java to 64 bit and that seemed to fix it. Here's a link that may help someone else also troubleshoot the similar issues I was experiencing; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42538223/ngramtokenizer-not-working-as-expected#comment87863385_42538223